# Mysql - Query UPDATE at vnum END in number 7

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I need to correct this query! Thank!

I try:

```
UPDATE `item_proto_copy2` 
SET `socket_pct`='1' 
WHERE `vnum` END AS 7 AND `type`=1
```

Comment: The `END AS` does not belong there. It is the final piece of a CASE statement which you do not have in your code.

Comment: what do you want on this condition `WHERE vnum END AS 7 AND type=1`?

Comment: What are you trying to do where you put `WHERE vnum END AS 7`?

Comment: PROBLEM:

Vnum have much numbers, exemple:

19294
19288
19927

I just want to put this rule on the END AT 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean?

```
UPDATE `item_proto_copy2` 
SET `socket_pct`='1' 
WHERE `vnum` = 7 AND `type`=1
```

if not, *follow-up question*, what do you want on this condition `WHERE vnum END AS 7 AND type=1`?

**UPDATE 1**

```
UPDATE `item_proto_copy2` 
SET `socket_pct`='1' 
WHERE RIGHT(`vnum`, 1) = '7' AND `type`=1
```

- [RIGHT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_right)

Comment: PROBLEM:

Vnum have much numbers, exemple:

19294
19288
19927

I just want to put this rule on the END AT 7.

Answer (score 2):

@JW's answer works by converting the `vnum` to a `CHAR` and then chopping it off with the `RIGHT()` function, keeping only the first character from the right:

```
WHERE RIGHT(vnum, 1) = '7'
```

You could also use `LIKE` in a similar way (implicit conversion to `CHAR` and then checking the right-most character):

```
WHERE vnum LIKE '%7'
```

And if the numbers are non-negative integers, this would work too, using modular arithmetic:

```
WHERE vnum MOD 10 = 7
```

Comment: @ypercube `like` is moderate but +1 `mod` is precisely greater/faster :)

Answer (score 1):

Guessing at what you're trying to do in your where clause.  The `END` does not belong in your WHERE clause and you cannot use `AS` in a WHERE clause either.

```
UPDATE `item_proto_copy2` 
SET `socket_pct`='1' 
WHERE `vnum` = 7 AND `type`=1
```

Comment: PROBLEM:

Vnum have much numbers, exemple:

19294
19288
19927

I just want to put this rule on the END AT 7.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I guess I incorrectly guessed at what you are trying to do.  JW's answer is correct.  Next time you may want to describe what you are trying to do in your question.